# Ошибка CS7036 помогите пофиксить

Tags: c#

Ошибка:

> CS7036    Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному
>   параметру "services" из "CommandService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly,
>   IServiceProvider)".

```
public class CommandHeadler {
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

    private CommandService _service;
    public CommandHeadler(DiscordSocketClient client) {
        _client = client;

        _service = new CommandService();

        _service.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
    }
    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage s) {
        var msg = s as SocketUserMessage;
        if (msg == null) return;

        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);

        int argPos = 0;
        if (msg.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos)) {
            var result = await _service.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos);

            if (!result.IsSuccess && result.Error != CommandError.UnknownCommand) {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну написано же...

Comment: Сколько параметров в `AddModulesAsync(Assembly, IServiceProvider)` и сколько вы передаете? :)

Comment: я в с# 0 только вот только учусь можете как-то попроще донести свою мысль?

Comment: Если вы в C# новичок, то может сначала начать с основ, а не браться сразу за сложное не понимая как и что работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ошибке указано, что функция принимает два аргумента

```
CommandService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly, IServiceProvider)
```

Ты передаешь только один

```
_service.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
```

Нужно передавать два, [второй параметр должен иметь тип IServiceProvider](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.CommandService.html#Discord_Commands_CommandService_AddModulesAsync_System_Reflection_Assembly_System_IServiceProvider_), если у тебя нет сервис провайдера можно передать null

```
_service.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), null)
```